# Add query string to a URL

Tags: javascript, url

I have written this code which adds a `querystring` to a URL:

```
exports.addQueryString = function(url, queryString) {
  var isQuestionMarkPresent = url && url.indexOf('?') !== -1,
    separator = '';

  if (queryString) {
    separator = isQuestionMarkPresent ? '&' : '?';
    url += separator + queryString;
  }

  return url;
};
```

Is there any way I can write this better?

Usage:

```
addQueryString('http://example.com', 'q=1&val=3&user=me');
```

Comment: Have you considered proper encoding of query string values? From your code it looks like it might be a separate operation since you already pass in a full query string but may be relevant overall.

Comment: @PeterMonks Yes..That is indeed a great point but I handled this case later (after I posted the question here). Once again thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is ok, only that i see not necesary make `url.indexOf('?')` if queryString is empty, because you are not going to use it.

```
exports.addQueryString = function(url, queryString) {   
  if (queryString) {
    var isQuestionMarkPresent = url && url.indexOf('?') !== -1,
      separator = isQuestionMarkPresent ? '&' : '?';
    url += separator + queryString;
  }

  return url;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you just want to add a single `queryString` to and already long `queryString`? You would need to know the entire `queryString` to do that, just to add a single new value.

What your function should do is take a single `queryString` value and if it already exists it should update it and if it doesn't exist it should append it.